# ESP32-C3 Custom Board. Programs with function generator but not with cystal

Tags: esp32

We are currently working on a project with a chip down of the ESP32-C3-mini and we are using the ESP32-C3FN4. The issue we are having is the ESP will only program when we are using a function generator @40MHz but when we using a 40MHz crystal it wont. The other weird thing is that the ESP will run and return things as expected with both the crystal and the FG. I have attached a picture of the schematic.[image: Schematic]